# Same id, different name, how to get name by another name?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table:

```
id     name
1      j
1      jack
1      john
```

So I have `j` and want find all names which id is equal to the id of `j` in single SQL?

Comment: Might be off-topic but curious as to why you would have your id all the same..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name
from your_table
where id in
(
   select id from your_table where name = 'j'
)
```

Comment: @hawk: I like the syntax in my answer. That is why I chose it. So please don't modify syntax unless it is really wrong. And please don't do minor edits. People need to review those and your changes should be worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

Self join time

```
select t1.name
from your_table t1
inner join your_table t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t2.name = 'j'
```